# onPremisesDirectorySynchronization has no option to disable DirSync

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I cannot see there is any value in the response from GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/directory/onPremisesSynchronization that indicates you can disable DirSync using Microsoft Graph.

Has anyone figured out how you can disable on-premise directory sync using Microsoft Graph?

By running GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/directory/onPremisesSynchronization in the Microsoft Graph Explorer tool, no result is returned which indicates DirSync can be disabled with Graph.

Comment: What if you disable all features? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onpremisesdirectorysynchronizationfeature?view=graph-rest-beta

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not help, I have a hunch the feature is not supported. However, I would like to disable AD sync and convert my users to 'in-cloud' using Graph.

Answer (score 0):

Found other way you can Turn off directory synchronization for Microsoft 365 using the PowerShell:

You can use PowerShell to turn off directory synchronization and convert your synchronized users to cloud-only. However, it is not recommended that you turn off directory synchronization as a troubleshooting step. If you need assistance with troubleshooting directory synchronization, see the Fixing problems with directory synchronization for Microsoft 365 article.

[image]

For more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/turn-off-directory-synchronization?view=o365-worldwide#turn-off-directory-synchronization

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, but I am looking to specifically do this with PowerShell or the Graph API.